# how to send HTTPS request to a self-sign cartificate FLASK server with android?

Tags: android, https

I made a certificate using openSSL with the following cmd:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -out cert.pem -keyout key.pem -days 365
```

and run with the certificate and the key a FLASK server

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, ssl_context=('cert.pem', 'key.pem'))
```

I observe that using the browser\Postman after accepting the warning I can access the server but,

for reading more about FLASK server and certificate please see https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/running-your-flask-application-over-https

**how can I send a POST\GET requests to my FLASK server?**

Answer (score 0):

Android supports the  "Real" certificate (lets encrypt as one of them) by default. when running a server not on a domain but on an IP unfortunately there is no support for the "REAL" CA providers.

when using self-sign server one can provide the client with the self sign CA (not the key!) add the CA to the know CA's. I am not a security expert but that way a man in the middle attack is not possible

1.conver the .pem to .crt -  android do not support `.pen` but instead `.crt`

```
openssl x509 -outform der -in cert.pem  -out cert.crt
```

and move the new `cert.crt` to the **assets** folder in you android project.

2. in your client code:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground started" );
        HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            String urlString = strings[0];
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            // adding the ca
            SSLContext sslContext= SslUtils.getSslContextForCertificateFile("cert.crt",context);
            urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
            // additional settings
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
            // match CA host name to the url 
            urlConnection.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                @Override
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                   //allowedHosted is a pre-defined list with the allowed host names as strings
                   for (String allowHost : allowedHostes){
                       if (allowHost.equals(hostname)) {
                           return true;
                       }
                   }
                   return false;
                }
            });

            int code = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
            if (code !=  200) {
                throw new IOException("Invalid response from server: " + code);
            }

            // normal code to continue....
```

the SslUtils class is taken directly from here
https://mklimek.github.io/trust-specific-certificate-on-jvm/

(the example here extends AsyncTask  - for learning about http with async in android: https://medium.com/@JasonCromer/android-asynctask-http-request-tutorial-6b429d833e28)